# PYTHON SSL - The difference between two ways to set up a ssl connection

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, client

I'm trying to set up a connection using ssl between a client and a server that I develop.
Base on this : http://bobthegnome.blogspot.fr/2007/08/making-ssl-connection-in-python.html
I created a simple connection and it work. But I want to improve it by adding a client authentication. So I found that some people use socket.warp_socket .

Here is an example :

```
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9998))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                            server_side=True,
                            certfile="srv.crt",
                            keyfile="srv.key",
                            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    deal_with_client(connstream)
```

What is the difference between these two? Witch one is the best (in my case)?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

`socket.ssl()` is a deprecated method that calls `socket.wrap_socket()` underneath, just does some checking whether python has been compiled with SSL support (which `import ssl` will do for you in any case).

```
def ssl(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None):
    # we do an internal import here because the ssl
    # module imports the socket module
    import ssl as _realssl
    warnings.warn("socket.ssl() is deprecated.  Use ssl.wrap_socket() instead.",
                  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
    return _realssl.sslwrap_simple(sock, keyfile, certfile)
```

Comment: ssl.wrap_socket is also deprecated now.